# (SQL ZOO) Lead actor in Julie Andrews movies

Tags: sql

SQL Zoo
https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations
No. 12：
Lead actor in Julie Andrews movies
List the film title and the leading actor for all of the films 'Julie Andrews' played in.

Did you get "Little Miss Marker twice"?
Julie Andrews starred in the 1980 remake of Little Miss Marker and not the original(1934).

Title is not a unique field, create a table of IDs in your subquery (What does this mean?)

What I wrote was this but it says I'm wrong, don't know why:

```
SELECT title, name 
FROM (movie JOIN casting ON movie.id = casting.movieid) JOIN actor ON actor.id = casting.actorid
WHERE title IN 
(SELECT title FROM casting JOIN actor ON casting.actorid = actor.id
where actor.name = 'Julie Andrews')
AND ord = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE title IN 
(SELECT title FROM casting JOIN actor ON casting.actorid = actor.id
where actor.name = 'Julie Andrews')
```

There is no `title` column in either `casting` or `actor`. So you have accidentally correlated this subquery - the title is scoped from outside the subquery so you effectively have something like

```
where 1 in 
  (select 1 
   from casting JOIN actor ON casting.actorid = actor.id
   where actor.name = 'Julie Andrews'
  )
```

Which will be true if that subquery returns any rows. Always be clear which row source a column should come from.

You probably meant to select the `movieid` column from `casting` and use that as a filter against `movie.id` similar to your join in the first subquery:

```
SELECT movie.title, actor.name 
FROM movie 
JOIN casting ON movie.id = casting.movieid
JOIN actor ON actor.id = casting.actorid
WHERE movie.id IN 
(SELECT casting.movieId FROM casting JOIN actor ON casting.actorid = actor.id
where actor.name = 'Julie Andrews')
AND casting.ord = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick go, this goes the trick

```
    /* Create a derived table of the relevant IDs*/
    with j as (
      select movieid
      from casting c join actor a on a.id=c.actorid
      where a.name='julie andrews'
      )
  /*
 Now use this as a starting point to join to the
 relevant tables to fetch the required actors from
 the movieIDs from the derived table
  */
      select m.title, a.name
      from j join movie m on m.id=j.movieid
      join casting c on c.movieid=j.movieid
      join actor a on a.id=c.actorid
      where c.ord=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.title AS film_title, a.name AS leading_actor
FROM movie m
JOIN casting c ON m.id = c.movieid
JOIN actor a ON c.actorid = a.id
WHERE m.id IN (
    SELECT movieid
    FROM casting
    WHERE actorid = (
        SELECT id
        FROM actor
        WHERE name = 'Julie Andrews'
    )
)
AND c.ord = 1;
```